# Implementing IEquatable in a base class and use it in all the derived classes

Tags: .net, vb.net, interface, containers

I have a base class which implements the IEquatable interface:

```
Public MustInherit Class DaoBase : Implements IEquatable(Of DaoBase)

        MustOverride Function getPrimaryKey() As Integer

        Shadows Function Equals(other As DaoBase) As Boolean Implements IEquatable(Of DaoBase).Equals
            Return getPrimaryKey() = other.getPrimaryKey
        End Function

        Overrides Function GetHashCode() As Integer
            Return getPrimaryKey()
        End Function

        ' more things here
 End Class
```

All the subclasses must provide a `getPrimaryKey` method.

```
Public Class Packaging
        Inherits DaoBase

    Public Sub New(id As Integer)
        Me.id = id
    End Sub

    Overrides Function getPrimaryKey() As Integer
        Return id
    End Function

    <DaoField> Property id As Integer

End Class
```

`List(Of Packaging).Contains` never calls the `Equals` method as expected.

```
Dim packs As new List(Of Packaging)()
Dim pack As New Pack(1)
Dim pack2 As New Pack(1)
packs.Add(pack)
```

Now, `packs.Contains(pack)` <- TRUE, OK, reference equality

But, `packs.Contains(pack2)` <- FALSE, NOK!

I don't want to "remember" to implement `IEquatable` in the derived classes.

Is there a way to force derived to implement their `IEquatable`, or, even better, to make `Contains` call the base class `DaoBase.Equals`?

Comment: Are you missing `()` at the end of this line `getPrimaryKey() = other.getPrimaryKey` ?

Comment: Your code should just work - it's a classic implementation of the [*Template Method*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern) design pattern.

Comment: IEquatable<T> is meant for structs no?

Comment: No, it doesn't work, because IEquatable is defined for the base class and it is never called.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I've found is to generic-ize the base class:

```
Public MustInherit Class DaoBase(Of T) : Implements IEquatable(Of T)

    MustOverride Shadows Function Equals(other As T) As Boolean Implements IEquatable(Of T).Equals
    MustOverride Overrides Function GetHashCode() As Integer

End Class

Public Class Packaging
    Inherits DaoBase(Of Packaging)

    Public Sub New(id As Integer)
        Me.id = id
    End Sub

    Overrides Function Equals(other As Packaging) As Boolean
        Return GetHashCode() = other.GetHashCode()
    End Function

    Overrides Function GetHashCode() As Integer
        Return id
    End Function

    Property id As Integer
End Class
```

Now Equals must be overridden and specialized on the derived type.

```
    Dim p1 As New Packaging(1)
    Dim p2 As New Packaging(1)

    Dim packs As New List(Of Packaging)
    packs.Add(c1)

    Debug.Print(packs.Contains(c1))         <- TRUE
    Debug.Print(packs.Contains(c2))         <- TRUE
```

But I have to write many identical Equals methods in all the derived classes. I was looking for a way to avoid this.